# forall in a kind signature

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, data-kinds, singleton-type

In [singletons-2.6](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.6), [`Sigma`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.6/docs/Data-Singletons-Sigma.html#t:Sigma) is defined as

```
data Sigma (s :: Type) :: (s ~> Type) -> Type
```

and GHC 8.8.4 tells that its kind is

```
> :k Sigma
Sigma :: forall s -> (s ~> *) -> *
```

So what is this `forall` in this kind signature?

Apparently, it's different from

```
data Sigma :: forall s. Type -> (s ~> Type) -> Type
```

in which case its kind is, of course,

```
Sigma :: * -> (s ~> *) -> *
```

Also, it seems different from

```
data Sigma :: f s -> (s ~> *) -> *
```

It seems to me that the promoted kind of the type variable `s` in `s :: Type` is unified with the kind variable `s` in `(s ~> Type) -> Type`, but does it what happens? I have a feeling that I'm missing something very basic.

I tried finding any documents describing this, but I had no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is that `K :: forall s. F s -> T` means that `K` takes one argument, and that `s` is inferred from that. Instead, `K :: forall s -> F s -> T` should mean that `K` takes two arguments, and that the value of the first must agree with the type of the second, similarly to what happens for dependently typed functions in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I got some ideas from [dependent haskell](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/dependent-haskell) in GHC Wiki.

We can now pass a kind to a type constructor just like we can pass a type to a data constructor (we still need to pass a singleton instead of a type itself though).

In this declaration of `Sigma`,

```
data Sigma (s :: Type) :: (s ~> Type) -> Type
```

`s` in `s :: Type` is a kind variable of `Type` kind-kind and this kind has to be passed explicitly when you use `Sigma`. And in its kind signature,

```
Sigma :: forall s -> (s ~> *) -> *
```

`forall s` means `s` is a visible kind. It means you need to pass it explicitly when you say it's visible. You can read it as `Sigma` is a type constructor taking a kind `s` and a type of kind `s ~> Type`, and returning a type of kind `Type`.

You cannot write this type signature directly in GHC 8.8.4, but you can write it using [`StandaloneKindSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-StandaloneKindSignatures) in GHC 8.10.1.

**Update (2021/9/30)**:

It's called Visible Dependent Quantification. You can find a good explanation about it at [Visible dependent quantification in Haskell](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2019/03/15/visible-dependent-quantification-in-haskell/).